# Howto delete ecs service with ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to delete an ecs service with ansible:

```
- name: Delete the Service
  ecs_service:
    name: "{{ service_name }}"
    cluster: "{{ cluster_name }}"
    state: absent
```

It fails with:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the DeleteService operation: The service cannot be stopped while the primary deployment is scaled above 0.
```

So the solution would be to set the "desired_count" to 0 before deleting the service. But how do I do that ansible?
Or, what is the correct way of deleting a running ecs service in ansible?

Comment: You probably want to use `ecs_service_facts` to determine whether the service exists and what the desired_count and current count are, then conditionally set desired to 0 if it is not already. If the `ecs_service`  module doesn't automatically wait for the count to drop, use `ecs_service_facts` again in an `until` loop until the count reaches 0, then set the state to absent with `ecs_service`

Comment: That said, I would call this a bug in the ecs_service module that would benefit from a pull request to allow it to do all these things automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same problem and figured out how to avoid this problem.
As you've already figured out: The "desired count" value has to be set to '0'.

Unfortunately in Ansible you can do this only in a 2-step-way like this:

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False`

  tasks:

#update the service as you would do in console or cli, 
# so that desired count is set to 0
    - ecs_service:
        name: jenkins-service
        state: present
        cluster: jenkins-cluster
        desired_count: 0
        task_definition: jenkins-task

#now you're able to delete the service definition.
    - ecs_service:
        name: jenkins-service
        state: absent
        cluster: jenkins-cluster
```

I'm sorry for my bad markdown skills. But I hope that helps though.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in the event that the TaskDefinition is inactive: "botocore.errorfactory.ClientException: An error occurred (ClientException) when calling the UpdateService operation: TaskDefinition is inactive".  Any idea how to resolve this case?

Comment: Just an idea: You could try to newly register the taskdefinition in ansible with the module: "ecs_taskdefinition"

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the below changes: ecs_service: name: test-sample-app-service operation: delete cluster: test-sample-app-cluster